# ¿los datos no se insertan en la BD?

Tags: php, base-de-datos, formularios

HTML

```
<!-- CUERPO DEL FORMULARIO -->
    <div class="t945">
    <div class="adaptable">
    <div class="Form-Corp">
       <form  action="correo.php" method="POST" autocomplete="off" class="Form-Caja">
          <div class="Form-Principal">
           <h1 class="Form-Title">Arma Tu Pizza</h1>
           </div>
           <input type="text" id="input-totalmente-falso" style="display: none">
           <label for="Nombre" class="Form-Label"></label>
           <input type="text" autofocus autocomplete="off" id="Nombre" class="Input-Form" name="Name" placeholder="Nombre" required>
           <label for="Correo" class="Form-Label"></label>
           <input type="text" autocomplete="off" id="Correo" class="Input-Form" name="Correo" placeholder="Correo" required>
           <label for="Direccion" class="Form-Label"></label>
           <input type="text" autocomplete="off" id="Direccion" class="Input-Form" name="Direccion" placeholder="Direccion" required>
           <label for="Elige tu Sabor" class="Form-Label"></label>
           <input type="text" autocomplete="off" id="Paladar" class="Input-Elige" name="Sabor" placeholder="INGREDIENTES" required>
           <input type="radio" class="button1" name="Pago" value="EFECTIVO" checked><p class="PA-1">Efectivo</p><br>
           <input type="radio" class="button2" name="Pago" value="PUNTO DE VENTA" checked><p class="PA-2">Punto De Venta</p><br>
           <a href="javascript:PRICE()"><input type="button" id="Consultar" class="Input-Price" value="Mostrar Ingredientes"></a>
           <div class="tot">
              <label class="DIV" for="txtValor"></label>
              <input  type="text" name="tot" readonly id="txtValor" value="0" />
          </div>
           <input  id="SEND" type="image"  img src="send.png" height="50px" width="50px" class="Boton-Submit" name="Submit" value="enviar">
           <p class="Form-Label1">PEDIDOS</p>
       </form>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
```

PHP donde insertara los datos

```
<?php
include ("Connect.php");

$Nombre=$_POST['Name'];
$Correo=$_POST['Correo'];

$query="INSERT INTO message (Nombre, Correo,) 
VALUES ('".$Nombre."','".$Correo."')";

$Resultado=$Conexion->query($query);

if($Resultado){
    echo "Los Datos Se Ingresaron Correctamente"

}else{
    echo "no se han podido ingresar los datos"
}


    ?>
```

php conexion

```
<?php
 $Conexion=@mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "CLIENTES"); or die ("No se ha podido establecer Conexion con el servidor");
?>
```

.... **YA RESUBI** el codigo del html para que lo vean completo , y en cuanto a error no me tira ni uno solo me lleva a la pagina que dice enviado exitosamente pero cuando reviso la base de dato no hay nada insertado

¿tambien quería preguntar aparte no tiene que ver nada con la base de datos pero se pueden agregar dos action en un mismo formulario?

Comment: Por favor tu código como texto y no como imagen

Comment: ¿Qué mensaje aparece?

Comment: Para empezar, tu PHP no es válido, te estará generando errores 500 porque no estás poniendo el punto y coma al final de los `echo "Los Datos Se Ingresaron Correctamente"`. A partir de ahí puede seguir mirando lo que te responden (error SQL).

Comment: como mencione , cuando utilizo el formulario y escribo todo los datos al final no sale ningún error,

Answer (score 1):

Empieza por quitar la coma que hay detrás del campo "Correo"

```
$query="INSERT INTO message (Nombre, **Correo,**) 
VALUES ('".$Nombre."','".$Correo."')";
```

Debe quedar así

```
$query="INSERT INTO message (Nombre, Correo) 
VALUES ('".$Nombre."','".$Correo."')";
```

Al mismo tiempo, aunque en tu código no aparece, entiendo que tienes en el formulario el campo correo, el botón de envío y el cierre del formulario y en caso contrario, debes añadirlo.

```
<input type="text" autofocus autocomplete="off" id="Correo" class="Input-Form" name="Correo" placeholder="Correo" required>
<input type="submit" value="Enviar formulario">
</form>
```

Si aún así fallara, como te han dicho, indica que mensaje de error te da para que podamos saber que podría estar pasando.

Comment: Al haber puesto solo parte del código di por sentado, tal vez erroneamente, que tendrá completados el resto de campos, porque entiendo que tendrá implementado el botón de envío y cerrado el formulario. Edito la respuesta para aclararlo.

Comment: el coding donde puse el cierre de de campo de formulario , lo puse bien del HTML solo mostrémosla la parte que quiero que envíe a la base de datos

Comment: ¿Continúa sin funcionar quitando la coma que hay detrás del campo correo como te comento en la respuesta?

Comment: sigue sin insertar **nada**

Answer (score 0):

buenas noches gracias por la recomendación con la publicación,el día de hoy le realice una correcciones al código, lo dividí en dos archivos

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>form</title>
</head>

<body>
 <form action="" id="form">
  <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Nombre" name="name" value="">
  <input type="email" id="correo" placeholder="correo" name="correo" value="">
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">enviar</button>
 </form>

</body>

<script>

let frmAdd=document.querySelector("form")
frmAdd.addEventListener('submit',(even)=>
{
  even.preventDefault()

  const formdt=new FormData(frmAdd)

  add(formdt)

  let nm=formdt.get("name")
  console.log(nm)
  frmAdd.reset();
})


function add(dt)
{
  const url='./server.php'
  fetch(url,
  {
    method:'POST',
    body:dt,
  })
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then((dt) => 
  {
   console.log(dt.msj)
  })
  .catch(function(err) 
  {
  console.log(err);
  });
}

</script>

</html>
```

En el primer código cree una estructura HTML  básica,en la que agregue un formulario con un ID

```
<form action="" id="form">
```

Para seleccionarlo con el método querySelector de JS y almacenarlo en una variable frmAdd

```
 let frmAdd=document.querySelector("form")
```

Una vez almacenado en una variable,escucho el evento submit con el método addlistener,el cual ejecuta un callback

```
frmAdd.addEventListener('submit',(even)=>
```

con el siguiente codigo evito que se ejecute la accion por defecto del  metodo submit que es recargar la pagina

```
even.preventDefault()
```

luego declaro una constante

```
const formdt=new FormData(frmAdd)
```

en la que hago instancia al objeto FormData y le paso como parámetro la variable frmAdd. luego ejecuto la función add y paso como parámetro formdt

```
add(formdt)
```

esta funcion tiene dentro el metodo fetch ,que es una manera de hacer peticiones ajax mas sencilla.

url tiene la direccion nombre del archivo php que tiene la conexión a la base de dato, en mi prueba lo llame server.php

```
const url='./server.php'
  fetch(url,
  {
    method:'POST',
    body:dt,
  })
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then((dt) => 
  {
   console.log(dt.msj)
  })
  .catch(function(err) 
  {
  console.log(err);
  });
```

codigo php

```
<?php

$nombre=$_POST['name'];
$correo=$_POST['correo'];

if ($nombre !="" && $correo!="")
{
 //estableces la conexion
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "CLIENTES");
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Falló la conexión con MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}
//en caso de que la conexion sea exitosa  
//creas tu consulta

$q="INSERT INTO message (Nombre, Correo,)
VALUES ($nombre,$correo)";

//ejecutas
$mysqli->query($q);

echo"agregado";
}else
{
    $msj=new stdClass();
    $msj->msj='campos vacios';
    echo json_encode($msj);
}
?>
```

parar poder hacer referencia al valor de los input, FormData toma como referencia el nombre que coloques en el atributo name

Comment: Por favor evita responder con solo imágenes, en este punto vuelve poco comprensible tu aporte